# How to bind multiple textures to primitives drawn using `glDrawRangeElements()`?

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I am using `glDrawRangeElements()` to draw textured quads (as triangles). My problem is that I can only bind one texture before that function call, and so all quads are drawn using the same texture.

How to bind a different texture for each quad?
Is this possible when using the `glDrawRangeElements()` function? If not, what other OpenGL function should I look at?

Answer (score 2):

First,you need to give an access to multiple textures inside your fragment shader.To do this you can use :

[Arrays Textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture)  -basically 3D texture,where 3rd dimension is the number of different 2D texture layers.The restriction is that all the textures in the array must be of the same size.Also Cube Map textures can be used (GL 4.0 and later) to stack multiple textures.

[Bindless textures](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/bindless_texture.txt) - these you can use on relatively new hardware only.For Nvidia that's Kepler and later.Because bindless texture is essentially a pointer to a texture memory on GPU you can fill an array or Uniform buffer with thousands of those and then index into that array in the fragment shader having an access to the sampler object directly.

Now,how can you index into those arrays per primitive?There are number of ways.First,you can use [instanced drawing](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html) if you render the same primitives several times.Here you have GLSL InstanceID to track what primitive is currently drawn.
In case when you don't use instancing and also try to texture different parts of geometry in a single draw call it would be more complex.You should add texture index information on per vertex basis.That's ,if your geometry has interleaved structure per vertex looking like this:

VTN,VTN,VTN...  where (V-vertices,T-texture coords,N-normals),you should add another set of data ,let's call it I - (texture index),so your vertex array will
have the structure VTNI,VTNI,VTNI...
You can also set a separate Vertex buffer including only the texture indices.But for large geometry buffers it probably will be less efficient.Interleaving of usually allows faster data access.
Once you have it you can pass that texture index as varying into fragment shader(set as flat to make sure it is not interpolated ) and index into specific texture.Yeah,that means your vertex array will be larger and contain redundant data,but that's the downside of using multitexture on a single primitive level.

Hope it helps.